# Turn PHP string-based-query into dynamic Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, nosql

I'm trying to make a NoSQL script for myself. Yet I've always liked the "one-line-query" method, used by MySQL. For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
```

If I would want to use the same query using plain PHP, I'd end up using an array. Like this:

```
$sql = array(
    "SELECT" => "id, firstname, lastname",
    "FROM" => "MyGuests",
);
```

Even though it works fine this way, it's just not as elegant as it could be. I've tried the PHP explode function:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$sql_query = explode(" ", $sql);
```

Which would output:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => SELECT
        [1] => id,
        [2] => firstname,
        [3] => lastname
        [4] => FROM
        [5] => MyGuests
    )
```

Now you could say: `$sql_query[0]` equals SELECT, `$sql_query[4]` equals FROM. Yet the problem is: those values are not fixed. When I would add a condition like "WHERE", I'd have to make an if-else statement for every single scenario. And the amount of values for SELECT (in this case (3): id, first name, lastname) would always be random. It could be more values, it could be less. Long story short: I'd end up spending hours making a PHP-script that pre-defines every possible scenario.

My question is: would there be a method to "convert" a string based query into an array, without having to pre-define everything? It has to find words like SELECT, UPDATE, WHERE, FROM, etc. and also take the value(s) that come after those things. So a more elegant and dynamic way.

Example:

```
"SELECT id, username FROM Users"
```

Should be converted into:

```
 $sql = array(
      "SELECT" => "id, username",
      "FROM" => "Users",
 );
```

And:

```
"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Country=US"
```

Or:

```
"SELECT * WHERE Country=US FROM Users"
```

Should be converted to:

```
$sql = array(
       "SELECT" => "*",
       "FROM" => "Users",
       "WHERE" => "Country=US",
);
```

It should know where the other word like (FROM, WHERE) starts, so it doesn't take that word as a value. And it should be able to be randomised.

(I'm sorry if this question is unclear, I'm still fairly new to PHP.)

Thanks in advance for taking your time to read this!

Comment: can you clear your requirement

Comment: @syamlal I've updated it.

Comment: _would there be a method to "convert" a string based query into an array_ - you need a proper SQL lexer to parse an arbitrary SQL

Comment: @user1597430 I get what you mean, yet I'm using a script called "SleekDB" which is a PHP based NoSQL database implementation. I just want to make it more like MySQL in the way it works.

Comment: Good Question. As far as I know there's no support for mysql query phase based separation in native PHP, you'll have to use some library which offers it or write some function yourself.

Comment: @RewCie I'm afraid that's the case indeed. Yet it shouldn't even be that complicated. It should know where to start (like SELECT) and know when to stop (when it reaches FROM for example) everything in between should be used as the value of SELECT. Yet the "random" part makes it rather complicated.

Comment: @MikRoeHollywoodGames It's easy, but I can't write answer rn, busy a bit, But you define an array with *defined* mysql phases like *select, *, from, xyz, blah, blah* and use a loop for the query variable `$sql` where the functions splits it whenever it encounters a defined mysql phase or unknown ones (like table name, column or whatever)

Comment: @RewCie Interesting approach. But how would it take the values? It has to know where it is and take the next following values, until a new word like SELECT, DELETE, etc. starts.

Comment: There are no easy way to achieve this. You can try with regular expressions but, since the query can be very complex, and contains it self the keywords, and sub queries... oufff. this is a titanic task.  But again, you can try with [regex](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)